# Sum squared difference for a list pairs with over 1.5 million items

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen this problem: [Sum of Square Differences (SSD) in numpy/scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284611/sum-of-square-differences-ssd-in-numpy-scipy)

However, I was wondering. My machine has 16-cores and 64GB RAM. Iterating a list of more than a million items in python to first get the prices then calculating the sum squared difference for 1 trading year and saving all the results back in a dataframe, is very time and energy consuming. Can I use multiprocessing to solve speed this process up?

```py
def SSD(list_of_tickers):
    start = time.time()
    ssd_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['stock1', 'stock2', 'corr', 'ssd'])
    for i in range(len(list_of_tickers)):
        price1 = price_pipeline.loc['2015-01-01':'2016-01-01', list_of_tickers[i][0]]
        price2 = price_pipeline.loc['2015-01-01':'2016-01-01', list_of_tickers[i][1]]
        ssd = np.sum((price1 - price2)**2)
        ssd_results.loc[i, 'ssd'] = ssd
        ssd_results.loc[i, 'stock1'] = list_of_tickers[i][0]
        ssd_results.loc[i, 'stock2'] = list_of_tickers[i][1]
        ssd_results.loc[i, 'corr'] = list_of_tickers[i][2]

    print('finished running in: {}'.format(time.time() - start))
    return ssd_results
```

These changes thank the discussion with Nick in the comment section significantly improved the speed (810 seconds):

```py
def SSD(list_of_tickers):
    start = time.time()
    ssd_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['stock1', 'stock2', 'corr', 'ssd'])
    list_ssd = []
    list_corr = []
    list_stock1 = []
    list_stock2 = []
    new_pipe = price_pipeline.loc['2015-01-01':'2016-01-01']
    for i in range(len(list_of_tickers)):
        price1 = new_pipe[list_of_tickers[i][0]]
        price2 = new_pipe[list_of_tickers[i][1]]
        ssd = np.sum((price1 - price2)**2)

        list_ssd.append(ssd)
        list_corr.append(list_of_tickers[i][2])
        list_stock1.append(list_of_tickers[i][0])
        list_stock2.append(list_of_tickers[i][1])

    print('finished running in: {}'.format(time.time() - start))
    ssd_results['stock1'] = list_stock1
    ssd_results['stock2'] = list_stock2
    ssd_results['ssd'] = list_ssd
    ssd_results['corr'] = list_corr
    
    return ssd_results
```

Comment: Your computer runs over a billion instructions per second, so doing a sum of square differences for a million entries will take around a millisecond. At that size, your program would spend more time in multiprocessing overhead than actually doing the calculation. Seems not worth bothering with, unless you're doing it for learning purposes.

Comment: How does that happen? So there is no way in speeding up this process? I would like to do for education purpose.

Comment: Iterating the list is fast. Creating the *new* list (or other data structure) of results, which will require quite a bit of memory allocation, is the slow part.

Comment: @NickODell It does not take a milisecond, were I to run this program using the full list, it would take a day.

Comment: @NickODell please check the latest edit. Whats your opinion?

Comment: I suspect part of it is the `.loc`. That's repeatedly doing a slicing operation on the dataframe, and I think you could do it before the loop.

Comment: @NickODell so good news! I made some changes, I did the slicing before the loop, calling it new_pipeline. Then used lists to store all the attributes then storing everything to the dataframe at the end. 100.000 runs in 50 seconds rather than what would have been maybe an hour. But the next step is, how can we make this go faster? Multi-processing?

Comment: Would be good if we knew what your data looks like...

Comment: In your second version you don't seem to use `i` for anything other than `list_of_tickers[i]`, so why not just iterate the list directly?

Comment: list_of_tickers is a list of 1.5million + items that consist of a tuple (ticker 1, ticker 2, correlation). Then in the for loop you it takes each item, get price for each ticker and then compute the sum squared difference. Append all the list and once running is finished to store everything to a dataframe.

Comment: @cem Are you interested in the pairwise SSE of *every* stock, or just a subset of them? If the answer is the former, I would point out that Scipy may be a faster approach. The function [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) with metric set to 'sqeuclidean' is equivalent to an SSE, and can calculate all distances at once.

Comment: It is the former, Ill check it out thank you for your help -  but is there a way to use multiprocessing ?

Comment: @cem Look into [Pool.map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) in the multiprocessing module. IMO, it's the easiest and best way to write multiprocessing code.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to reinvent the wheel. Instead, use vectorized calculations by using [numpy](https://numpy.org/). It works very well when doing calculations on vectors, here the columns of your dataframe.

Comment: Yes it does improve the speed.